# Kmymoney missing menu bar

Tags: 12.04, menu-bar, kmymoney

The other day I started Kmymoney only to find that the menu bar was missing. I've tried everything I can think of with no luck.  I've been looking on-line for several days now, also with no luck.  Ive even tried re-installing it but the issue still remains. I'm new to Ubuntu tho I've been using it since April and I'm now a true convert!  My greatest fear is that this is going to be something very simple and I'm going to have wasted everyones precious time.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 32-bit with GNOME 3.4.2 and my version of Kmymoney is 4.6.3.  I'm happy to supply any further information required and greatly appreciate the time and effort anyone gives to what I hope turns out to be the ignorance of a novice user.

Comment: Did you get this solved? I am having the same problem currently with Awesome WM.
I have also noted that the window only allows to be resized horizontally - it looks like it thinks the available screen height is not enough (~760px on the laptop).

Answer (score 2):

You might have the menu disabled in KMyMoney's resource file. I had the same problem switching from Ubuntu to Kubuntu (maybe because of Unity's "Global Menu"?).

Look for the resource file in your home directory:

```
~/.kde/share/config/kmymoneyrc
```

It's a regular text file, you can open it with your preferred text editor. Just make sure KMyMoney is not running. And if you are not comfortable editing configuration files, you should make a backup first.

Look for any occurrences of `MenuBar=Disabled` (could be more than one). Replace `Disabled` with `Enabled`, so it reads `MenuBar=Enabled`. Save the changes, and reopen KMyMoney.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to change this setting without messing directly with the file (which might lead to unexpected results/problems if not done carefully).